# MongoDB PHP accent problems

Tags: php, mongodb

Assume that I have inserted the following document with PHP (Note the "ó".)

```
$dbs->insert(array('name' => 'televisión'));
```

In mongodb database server is saved as follows

```
{ "name" : "televisi��n" }
```

If I invoke the findOne method as follow, (NOTE THE ó)

```
$doc = $dbs->findOne(array('name'   => "televisión"));
```

It return me the correct value

```
[name] => televisión
```

Everything fine until here.

So, imagine that from php I need to determine that the document televisión is into mongodb database, but I get the value from an URL without the accent "ó", i.e. television, so.

```
$doc = $dbs->findOne(array('name'   => "television"));
```

findOne method is returning null, so don't match the document.

Is there any way for this not return null value and can find the document regardless of the accent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to encode to utf8

Comment: Not specific to Mongo, but the exact same ago old problem: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @Sammaye I try it, but it store the document as follow televisi��n

Comment: THis question has nothing to do with utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

> In mongodb database server is saved as follows
>
> { "name" : "televisi��n" }

That's probably because your shell doesn't show UTF-8 properly.

As for:

> Is there any way for this not return null value and can find the document regardless of the accent?

You can do that with the new text search functionality:

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient;
$d = $m->test;
$c = $d->so;

// Just dropping here to create a controlled output - no need to do this yourself.
$c->drop();

$c->ensureIndex(
    array( 'name' => 'text' ),
    array( 'default_language' => 'spanish' )
);

$c->insert( array('name' => 'televisión' ) );

$res = $d->command( array( 'text' => 'so', 'search' => 'television' ) );

var_dump( $res['results'] );
?>
```

Which outputs:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    'score' =>
    double(1)
    'obj' =>
    array(2) {
      '_id' =>
      class MongoId#6 (1) {
        ...
      }
      'name' =>
      string(11) "televisión"
    }
  }
}
```

For text search to work, you need MongoDB 2.4.x, and you need to specifically enable it with the `--setParameter textSearchEnabled=true` flag to `mongod` or add to your code:

```
$d->command( array( 'setParameter' => 1, 'textSearchEnabled' => true ) );
```

Comment: When I try to use command method I get the following error: -- Call to undefined method MongoCollection::command(). -- I have mongodb 2.4.5 version installed

Comment: You need to call "command" on the database variable, not on the collection variable as my answer/example illustrates.

Comment: Why use a fts index for this? He is only trying to do a simple find() why bog and slow the inserts down with such a huge task of an index? I am sure there are better ways

Comment: @Derick It is necessary make drop to the collection before call ensureIndex method?

Comment: @evolquez No but it will need to buld the index if you don't

Comment: @Derick point taken, I tried your example in my code but doesn't work...I get the following error : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:####: text search not enabled' in /root/ Stack trace: #0 /root: MongoCollection->ensureIndex(Array, Array) #1 /root : eval()'d code(8)

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? The two last paragraphs explain that.